# Touch enabled monitors and Android

Tags: touchscreen, external-display

I need to buy new monitor for my PC and I'm thinking about touch enabled monitors like [DELL ST2220T](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=320-1819&~ck=baynoteSearch&baynote_bnrank=10&baynote_irrank=0) or [IIYAMA T2250MTS](http://www.iiyama.com/gb_en/products/prolite-t2250mts-1/). I recently bought Gooseberry Board with Android on it and it would be great if I could connect it by HDMI cable to one of these monitors and use touch screen like i would on a tablet. Does anybody know if Android can work with such touch enabled monitors? Maybe someone have touch enabled monitor and could check it somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The touch-screen part of a touch-screen monitor doesn't work over HDMI, but with a separate USB interface. It requires drivers specific to that monitor. To make it work with the Gooseberry Board under Android you'd have to find or write drivers for that monitor.