# How can I interface a 23 inch touch screen to a beagleboard?

Tags: touchscreen

Can I interface a 23 inch touch screen like [ACER T230H](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/MONITOR/2009/Acer/T230H/T230Hmv.shtml) with a beagleboard?

The screen has got HDMI in. Will the display scale automatically? Do I need to do kernel level changes in Android OS?

Comment: Are you running android on your beagleboard?

Comment: Beagle board can run many OS, including Android. Row boat is a special project for that purposes. Already there is a question on how to connect touch screen monitors to gooseberry board. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26855/touch-enabled-monitors-and-android

Comment: @ce4 yes i am running android on beagle board, and i need the output on a bigger display.

Comment: @Narayanan But there is no answer to that question

Comment: This seems like a rather narrow question to our generic Android Q&A site. You might be more lucky to ask this in in their [Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/rowboat), their IRC channel (#rowboat on freenode) or on the [bugtracker](http://code.google.com/p/rowboat/issues/list)). Feel free to update your question and answer it yourself if you find the solution on your own! Rowboat looks stale, by the way.